# Get an index of a sorted matrix

Tags: python, sorting, matrix, indexing

I have a 2D np.array:

```
array([[ 1523.,   172.,  1613.],
       [ 3216.,   117.,  1999.],
       [   85.,  1271.,     4.]])
```

I would to extract the sorted indexes of this np.array by value.
The results should be (for example) :
`[[2,2],[2,0],[1,1],[0,1],[2,1],[0,0],[0,2],[1,2],[1,0]]`

I already saw how to extract the min :

```
np.unravel_index(np.argmin(act),act.shape) #(2,2)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`numpy.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) with `axis=None` (assuming flatten array):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> act = np.array([[ 1523.,   172.,  1613.],
...                 [ 3216.,   117.,  1999.],
...                 [   85.,  1271.,     4.]])
>>> n = act.shape[1]
>>> zip(*np.argsort(act, axis=None).__divmod__(n))
[(2, 2), (2, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (2, 1), (0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0)]
```

Comment: @BenoitHugonnard, Sorry, I updated the answer to fix formatting issue.

Comment: Works just like a charm ! just had to cast as a list ;) Thank you !