# Simple way to get index of sorted matrix

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matrix

I would like to sort an entire matrix and get as a result a vector of indices. In R this can be simply achieved through the command

```
order("matrix")
```

In Python the analogous command would be:

```
np.argsort("matrix", axis=None)
```

The problem is that while R recognizes the index of a vector also for matrices (i.e. `matrix[1]` gives a number, not a row), in Python we seem to need always both indeces.

So I had to follow the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694080/get-an-index-of-a-sorted-matrix) question. But I need to change the code, since `zip()` seems to work correctly only together with `list()` in Python 3+ (or am I wrong?). The new code would be

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.array([[1,4,3],[2,8,0]])
n = a.shape[1]
d = list(zip( np.argsort(a, axis=None).__divmod__(n)))
d = list(zip(d[0][0], d[1][0]))
```

But the R code is so simple! Hence I wonder whether it is not possible to find a similarly simple command in Python. Or whether there is some similarly convenient way of treating a matrix also as a vector.

Comment: The R code is simple because a matrix is just a vector with dimension attribute in R. You are passing a vector to `order` since it simply ignores the `dim` attribute.

Comment: Yep, that is the issue. But isn't there a simple way to fool Python? I.e. to transform the vector index into the matrix index without those two ugly lines?

Comment: Is `d` your desired result?

Comment: Yes d is the required result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `d` is

```
In [362]: d
Out[362]: [(1, 2), (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1)]
```

`argsort` with `None` produces the sorted indices for a flattened version of the array:

```
In [366]: np.argsort(a, axis=None)
Out[366]: array([5, 0, 3, 2, 1, 4], dtype=int32)
In [368]: a.flat[_]           # apply this index to flattened a
Out[368]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8])
```

`np.argsort(a.flat)` does the same thing.  (or use `a.ravel()` if that makes more sense to you.)

We can `unravel` the 1d indices:

```
In [369]: np.unravel_index(Out[366], a.shape)
Out[369]: 
(array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32),
 array([2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1], dtype=int32))
```

This uses the same sort of `divmod` calculation that you do. It can be used to index `a` directly:

```
In [370]: a[_]
Out[370]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8])
```

`transpose` can turn that tuple of arrays into a 2d array similar to your `d`:

```
In [371]: np.transpose(__)
Out[371]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

(`np.argwhere` does the same thing with the results of `np.where`.)

Or in one line

```
In [375]: np.transpose(np.unravel_index(np.argsort(a, axis=None), a.shape)).tolist()
Out[375]: [[1, 2], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 2], [0, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Note that is type of list of index pairs cannot be used to index `a`.  `Out[369]` is the correct form for indexing items in a 2d array.  I'm not familiar with `R`, but it looks like its indexing style may be more like MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

> in Python we seem to need always both indeces

This is not true. You can access the elements of a 2D array (or an N-D array) with a flat index, like the indexes 5, 0, 3, 2, 1, 4 returned by `argsort`. This can be done by using [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), which creates a one-dimensional view into your n-dimensional array.

```
a = np.array([[1, 4, 3], [2, 8, 0]])
ix = np.argsort(a, axis=None)
print(a.ravel()[ix])
```

This prints [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8], the array elements are returned according to the indexes that argsort produced.

This can also be used for writing into the array: for example,

```
a.ravel()[ix[0]] = 42
```

replaces the smallest element of the array with 42.

Note that passing `axis=None` makes `argsort` implicitly flattened the array before sorting, an equivalent of `ravel` method.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that you could use ravel as a "way of seeing the matrix" without actually storing it. Unfortunately I can only accept one question!